# Codeigniter: Updating multiple rows in model

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-update

I've read similar questions and answers, still no idea, so do not shoot :)

I am trying this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 3 [paid_date] => 2013-06-25 20:37:35 [statement_status] => P ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 4 [paid_date] => 2013-06-25 20:37:35 [statement_status] => P ) )

$this->db->update_batch('credit_statement', $data, 'id');
```

and returns:

```
A Database Error Occurred
You must use the "set" method to update an entry.
```

and feel that I respected the Codeigniter book:

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'My date 2'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'Another date 2'
   )
);

$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'title'); 

// Produces: 
// UPDATE `mytable` SET `name` = CASE
// WHEN `title` = 'My title' THEN 'My Name 2'
// WHEN `title` = 'Another title' THEN 'Another Name 2'
// ELSE `name` END,
// `date` = CASE 
// WHEN `title` = 'My title' THEN 'My date 2'
// WHEN `title` = 'Another title' THEN 'Another date 2'
// ELSE `date` END
// WHERE `title` IN ('My title','Another title')
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Show your actual array definition PHP statement, not just the printed version.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: thank you guys, it was a misspelling, instead of $data I use $data_r :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't set the $data variable when you call it in the update_batch method.

Change this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 3 [paid_date] => 2013-06-25 20:37:35 [statement_status] => P ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 4 [paid_date] => 2013-06-25 20:37:35 [statement_status] => P ) )
```

To this:

```
$data = Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 3 [paid_date] => 2013-06-25 20:37:35 [statement_status] => P ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 4 [paid_date] => 2013-06-25 20:37:35 [statement_status] => P ) );
```

Comment: please check your array with var_dump or print_r

Comment: sorry, is set in the original code, that was just he array print... with print_r, sure

Comment: in fact is was an misspelling of the name of the array, so you showed me the error in an indirect way. you have my vote.